# How to create a local ADA Library with GPS?

Tags: gps, ada

I installed GPS and ADA and stated ready a couple of books ant looking at websites on Internet.

After doing a few of exercises, I transformed a couple to a local library since they where constantly used in further chapters.

I do not see (understand?) How I can setup a local library in the project file of the exercises.

Directory structure of my test environment:
[image: Directory structure of my test environment]

The file Test01 uses Basic_IO and Test02 uses Both Basic_IO and the generic Basic_Stack.

Here is the project file for Test01: 
[image: test01.adb]

Can someone explain to me how to get setup the lib so the program would compile and link?

Comment: It’d be a lot easier for us if you could supply text rather than images where possible, please

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create seperate project files (`.gpr` files) for `Basic_IO` and `Basic_Stack` and reference these project files (using `with`) in your test project files. You might want to take a look on [learn.adacore.com](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/GNAT_Toolchain_Intro/chapters/gprbuild.html#project-dependencies) and in the [GPRbuild user’s guide](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#organizing-projects-into-subsystems). I would also change the directory structure to (something like) this:

```
|
+-- learning_ada.gpr
|
+-- tests/
|   |
|   +-- test01/
|   |   |
|   |   +-- test01.gpr  
|   |   +-- obj/
|   |   +-- src/
|   |       |
|   |       +-- test01.adb
|   |      
|   +-- test02/
|       |
|       +-- test02.gpr  
|       +-- obj/
|       +-- src/
|           |
|           +-- test02.adb
|
+-- shared/
    |
    +-- basic_io/
    |   |
    |   +-- basic_io.gpr  
    |   +-- obj/
    |   +-- src/
    |       |
    |       +-- basic_io.ads
    |       +-- basic_io.adb
    |      
    +-- basic_stack/
        |
        +-- basic_stack.gpr  
        +-- obj/
        +-- src/
            |
            +-- basic_stack.ads
            +-- basic_stack.adb
```

The "library" projects could (in your case) remain quite simple. As an example, for `Basic_IO`, I'm pretty sure that something like

**basic_io.gpr**

```
project Basic_IO is
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
end Basic_IO;
```

could already work. This project can then be referenced from `test01.gpr` using

**test01.gpr**

```
with "..\..\shared\basic_io\basic_io.gpr";

project Test01 is
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("test01.adb");
end Test01;
```

Comment: If you look at the directory structure, you will see that this is exactly what I have: both .gps" & ".gpr" for both in the "src/lib" directory.

Comment: My apologies, I overlooked these files in your directory structure. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your library's gpr file should specify that it is a library, for example:

```pascal
library project Some_Library_Name is
   for Languages use ("Ada");
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Library_Name use "Some_Library_Name";
   for Library_Version use "1.0.0";
end Some_Library_Name;
```

Next, you need to add a `with Some_Library.gpr` statement to your client's gpr file. There are three ways to do is, in order of increasing initial complexity but also long-term utility.

## Relative dir (simplest)

You can `with Some_Dir/Another_Dir/library.gpr` specifying the directory from the client's gpr file to the library's gprfile. If this means going up with `..` that qualifies as a rather pungent code smell.

## Through `GPR_PROJECT_PATH`

To find the gprfile specified above, gprbuild will look in the current directory of the client gprfile, and in each directory given in `GPR_PROJECT_PATH`. You can find more information on this method in [AdaCore's own documentation of this variable](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#importing-projects).

For instance, if you had `C:/ada_projects` or `~/ada_projects` defined, and inside that were several libraries, you might add to your client.gpr file:

```
with Library_One/lib1.gpr
```

Or if you added each individual library's own directory to `GPR_PROJECT_PATH`, you would omit `Library_One` from the above.

If in resolving the `with` statement there are multiple matches, compilation will fail. (Thank you, Ada!)

Note this was previously called `ADA_PROJECT_PATH`, which still works but is deprecated.

## Alire Ada package manager (most flexible)

There are some problems with the above; it requires you to set things per-machine (or per-user) which, when you add a new developer to your team or need to set up a new computer, you will quickly run into as your projects won't compile until that is done. Next, you will run into versioning problems because you never wrote down which version of said libraries you were building against. Finally, even if you meticulously record that and inform your development team, you will still run into problems when you return to an old project after creating some new ones, and you find you want to use two different versions of the same library, which isn't possible with this approach.

Alire solves this in a similar way to Rust's cargo, python's pip, C#'s NuGet, Haskell's stackage and no doubt many others, by placing the library inside your client's directory, adding each library's root to `GPR_PROJECT_PATH`, building the project, and then resetting the environment again. If you have an online environment and only want to use, not publish alire package, then you don't need to know the details, you just add `with Project_File.gpr` (without relative directory) and run `alr build` instead of `gprbuild`.

Alire makes you record the version you want of each library, and allows for multiple versions of the same library being used in different projects, and even indirectly in the same project; i.e. library1 and library2 refer to different versions of sublibrary_foo, and your client can now include both library1 and library2; if it needs sublibrary_foo, it must include it itself or specifically include the version under library1 or library2.

AdaCore is working on support in GNATStudio (the new name for GPS 20 and beyond), in the meantime you can just run `alr build` from the commandline.

See the [official website](https://alire.ada.dev/) for more about Alire.

Comment: I believe I have to clarify a few points: 1) I am not running under Windows! I use GNATstudio under Linux Ubuntu. 2) I am staring to learn ADA in my free time, but I have started programming in the late '60s... 3) What I want to do is create a library of objects with the .ADS put in the same lib directory. That way I define the lib folder for compile and link.

Comment: 1) Your screenshots show this; I am also under linux; I am quite sure nothing in my answer depends on the operating system. 2) Ada is not an acronym. 3) I believe you can do that with each of the three methods I explain above. What about this doesn't work for you?

Comment: So, Ada is not like C/C++ where you can create a library of objects (.lib) and have the library element interfaces (.h) included in your sources

Comment: Yes, it is. I've put atop my answer how to specify that your library.gpr file is a library.

Comment: So, library.gpr specify the actual gprfiles sources, not the gpsfile templates of the modules?

Comment: @lelorrain Yes, the gprfile specifies the sources to be compiled in that project, but the second part of your question I don't understand. You can specify many things in a .gpr file, such as compiler flags, even how to compile C & C code that may be included. But I've never heard of modules having a 'template'.

Comment: In my limited view of Ada, the gps files define the interface of the modules that are referenced in the program to be compiled. That's what I call the templates. I was expecting to create a "library" of the modules.a objects that would be included at the link level, thus keeping the library sources independant of the program you are working on.